# How to call a PL/SQL stored function through Java EntityManager

Tags: java, sql, plsql, entitymanager

I have this function

```
create or replace
FUNCTION IFRS_FUNCTION_TEST RETURN NUMBER IS

estado NUMBER;
excepciones NUMBER;
title_code VARCHAR2(150 char);
colgaap_code VARCHAR2(150 char);
ifrs_code VARCHAR2(150 char);
v_causacion VARCHAR2(150 char);
pyg_diario_value VARCHAR2(150 char);
fecha_valoracion VARCHAR2(150 char);
pyg_dialogo VARCHAR2(150 char);

CURSOR ifrscursor IS SELECT no_asignado_por_la_entidad, codigo_puc FROM IFRS_351 WHERE no_asignado_por_la_entidad LIKE 'W%' FOR UPDATE;

BEGIN
        BEGIN
        estado:=0;
        excepciones:=0;
        OPEN ifrscursor;
        LOOP
            FETCH ifrscursor INTO title_code, colgaap_code; 
            EXIT WHEN ifrscursor%NOTFOUND;
            SELECT cta_ifrs into ifrs_code FROM ifrs_tabla_homo_351 WHERE codigo_puc_colgaap = colgaap_code;
            UPDATE IFRS_351 SET codigo_puc = ifrs_code WHERE CURRENT OF ifrscursor;
            BEGIN
                SELECT saldo, pyg_diario into v_causacion, pyg_diario_value FROM IFRS_INV_OBL WHERE nro_titulo=title_code;
                UPDATE IFRS_351 SET vr_mercado_o_valor_presente_ = v_causacion, causacion_valoracion_cuentas = pyg_diario_value WHERE CURRENT OF ifrscursor;
            EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                excepciones:=excepciones+1;
            END;
END LOOP; 
CLOSE ifrscursor;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    estado:=SQLCODE;  
END;
RETURN(estado);
```

How can I get the `estado` value of this function with Java `EntityManager`? I tried with

```
SELECT IFRS_FUNCTION_TEST() FROM DUAL;
```

but I always obtain the error code 14551.

Answer (score 2):

The value -14551 is actually an Oracle error rather than a value.  The error is detailed below and should give more details on exactly why it's not working.

> ORA-14551 cannot perform a DML operation inside a query   Cause: DML
>   operation like insert, update, delete or select-for-update cannot be
>   performed inside a query or under a PDML slave.   Action: Ensure that
>   the offending DML operation is not performed or use an autonomous
>   transaction to perform the DML operation within the query or PDML
>   slave.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `SELECT` query to retrieve the value of a function containing DML statements. You have to use an explicit call. something *like* that (untested):

```
Object result = em.createNativeQuery("{ ? = CALL IFRS_FUNCTION_TEST() }")
                    .getSingleResult();
```

---

EDIT: as this seems to *not* work, an other option is to send that query directly through JDBC (via `session.getConnection()`). Something *like* that probably:

```
CallableStatement statement = session.connection().prepareCall(
        "{ ? = CALL IFRS_FUNCTION_TEST() }");
statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);
//                                      ^^^^^
//                       use the right type here of course
statement.execute();
Object result = statement.getObject(1);
```

See the doc of [OracleCallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html) for details.

Comment: If I use createNativeQuery, I obtain an exception because the method is a function, not a procedure

Comment: @user3476922 Sorry, I can't test that now. Please try `"{CALL IFRS_FUNCTION_TEST()}"` or `"BEGIN ? :=  IFRS_FUNCTION_TEST(); END"`

Comment: The result is the same. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @user3476922 An that? `"{ ? = CALL IFRS_FUNCTION_TEST() }"` Same error message?

Comment: @user3476922 FWIW, I've edited my answer to provide an other option, using plain old JDBC.

Comment: Yes, because the method is a function, not a procedure

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `javax.persistence.EntityManager`:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

. . .

int estado;
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.doWork(connection -> {
    try (CallableStatement function = connection.prepareCall(
            "{ ? = call IFRS_FUNCTION_TEST() }" )) {
        function.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER );
        function.execute();
        estado = function.getInt(1);
    }
} );
```

These are the main dependencies to indicate what lib versions the solution works with:

```
compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4.0'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.7.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final'
```

As an alternative to `doWork()` and assigning the stored function result with `getXxx(1)`, you can use [`doReturningWork()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#doReturningWork-org.hibernate.jdbc.ReturningWork-).

As others pointed out, you cannot use a (native) query because of the `UPDATE` (DML) command inside the function.

### In Kotlin

Here's the solution in Kotlin (and using `doReturningWork`):

```
@PersistenceContext
lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

. . .

val session : Session = entityManager.unwrap(Session::class.java)
var estado = session.doReturningWork { connection: Connection ->
    connection.prepareCall(
            "{ ? = call IFRS_FUNCTION_TEST() }").use { function ->
        function.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER)
        function.execute()
        return@doReturningWork function.getInt(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA 2.0 doesn't support RETURN values, only calls.
The JPA 2.1 fixed this,

If you're using JPA 2.0.
My solution was. Create a FUNCTION calling PROCEDURE.
So, inside JAVA code you execute a NATIVE QUERY calling the oracle FUNCTION.

or else
use createStoredProcedureQuery